# Kubernetes for securing service endpoints?

Tags: spring, kubernetes, microservices, devops, netflix-eureka

So I have a very small micro service architecture built using Eureka service discovery. The problem I am facing right now is that I only want my service endpoints to accept request from my api gateway, as it is right now you can just make a request straight to the service and hit that service endpoint. Is this a problem Kubernetes would solve? Or Is there a more practical way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to expose the api gateway service then? Lock down all the other services to internal communication only?

Comment: @dijksterhuis Yes exactly that.

Comment: You don’t need Kubernetes to do that. You can accomplish the same thing with docker. Pretty sure you can connect every service to an internal network (including api gateway), then expose the api gateway container to the host. With kubernetes, you’ll probably need to look at pod networking and ingress controllers (ingress in k8s hurt my brain so I’ve personally avoided it).

Comment: I have zero knowledge of Eureka, or your service arch. But my point is, Kubernetes is just one way of doing this. Doesn’t Eureka have a config option to limit service discovery to internal vs external?

Comment: @dijksterhuis I can not find anything talking about Eureka internal settings, but thank you very much I will look into doing it with docker considering thats what I am using. Kubernetes seems like it would be quite the overkill for my project lol

Comment: Aye if it’s a small project, you don’t need Kubernetes. K8s is meant to handle mad levels of container orchestration over clusters of machines. Here are the docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/network/ - specifically look at bridge networks (internal only) and the host network (exposing a container to the host)

Comment: @dijksterhuis awesome, thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You should be using network policies to control the traffic between the services.

Answer (score 0):

In kubernetes the services you want to expose internally use service type ClusterIP. This is default anyway which means services are accessible within cluster only. your api gateway is exposed as load balancer service type which then takes traffic from external world and talks to services internally.  Depending on your cloud provider you can use firewall in front of load balancer since you can compromise security by simply exposing load balancer.  e.g. azure kubernetes you could use application gateway.  You can also replace the api gateway with ingress controller.  it's very powerful reverse proxy controller which you can expose directly to traffic and that would talk to your services internally.

You really need to understand concepts so i would recommend following links

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

https://blog.getambassador.io/kubernetes-ingress-nodeport-load-balancers-and-ingress-controllers-6e29f1c44f2d